# What is the difference between Android @NonNull and Jetbrains @NonNull

Tags: java, android, kotlin, annotations

What is the difference between these two annotations ?

- **`org.jetbrains.annotations.NonNull`**
- **`android.support.annotation.NonNull`**

Is <s>the kotlin compiler</s> IntelliJ going to honor **`android.support.annotation.NonNull`** and add assertions to check if I pass a null parameter to the corresponding java function ?

Is the Android lint going to honor **`org.jetbrains.annotations.NonNull`** and show me a warning if I check a variable that's already NonNull ?

When should I use one over the other ?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/nullable-and-notnull-annotations.html and https://developer.android.com/studio/write/annotations

Comment: From https://jetbrains.com/help/idea/nullable-and-notnull-annotations.html: `the IDE adds assertions to all methods and parameters annotated with the @NotNull annotation`. Does that mean the assertions won't be added if I compile from the command line ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `org.jetbrains.annotations.NonNull` IntelliJ IDEA spots that the contract is being violated. Done only if you are using IDE.

**Whereas**

`android.support.annotation.NonNull` is taken care by inspection tools like Lint. This is useful if you are running the inspection without using Android Studio or other IDE (e.g. Running through command line or through Jenkins)

**Edit:**

Based on the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#nullability-annotations) highlighted by `@user2340612` Kotlin compiler supports both of them. Since its supported at compiler level, it should work from Command-Line too.

Comment: Damn... Couldn't they agree on the same one ?

Comment: Based on [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#nullability-annotations), Kotlin compiler supports both, so probably it's worth using the "android flavor" in all cases

Comment: Just to be more precise, that's the part of the compiler dealing with nullable/non-nullable annotations: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/core/descriptors.jvm/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/load/java/JvmAnnotationNames.kt

Comment: That's cool ! That also mean the [doc](https://jetbrains.com/help/idea/nullable-and-notnull-annotations.html) is a bit misleading when it states that `the *IDE* adds assertions to all methods and parameters annotated with the @NotNull annotation`. It's actually the compiler, right ?

Comment: @mbonnin For Kotlin, yes. For Java , No.